# Type check on runtime loaded assembly

Tags: c#, .net, dll, mono

i'm facing a problem with using external dlls with mono at runtime. 
Suppose we have a framework dll containing an interface IMyInterface, a "plugin" project using this framework in which a class implements IMyInterface interface. 
This plugin, once deployed as dll, could be loaded from the framework itself at runtime, and all the classes which implements IMyInterface must be added to a collection within the framework. To do this, a type test must be done on all the types. Unfortunately, when I get all the types from the loaded dll, the type test fail even if the imported class is implementing a known interface. More precisely, the following statement

```
ImportedType.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IMyInterface))
```

returns false, even if the type actually implements IMyInterface. I suppose this is about imported type to be a System.RuntimeType, and not System.Type. But how can I deal with this issue? May be the interface IMyInterface has different signature across the same assembly used by different solutions?

Answer (score 0):

IsAssignableFrom is one of the most confusing method

```
typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(myObject.GetType())
typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(ImportedType)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Just tried the statements you wrote, and it doesn't work. I think it concern the fact that the imported type's base type is System.RuntimeType instead of System.Type actually, and this may create confusion...

Comment: I believe "ImportedType" is a type variable. What value is returned by ImportedType.FullName?

Comment: it is "System.MonoType". But to check the type I use ImportedType.BaseType, which value is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand you. ImportedType.FullName == "System.MonoType" or ImportedType.BaseType.FullName == "System.MonoType"

Comment: ImportedType.FullName == "System.MonoType"

Comment: Can you show how you get the "ImportedType" ? The "ImportedType" should not be a "System.MonoType" unless you take the BaseType of the type.

Comment: var the_assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assembly_path);
var the_types = the_assembly.GetTypes();
var ImportedType = the_types.Find(x => x.Name.Equals(NameOfTypeToImport));

Comment: It's make no sense, there is probably a code somewhere which assign ImportedType to the base type...So what return ImportedType.Name? "MonoType" or NameOfTypeToImport?

Comment: ImportedType.Name == NameOfTypeToImport. It is very, very strange. Moreover, I run this statement:

    ImportedType.GetInterfaces()[0].IsEquivalentTo(typeof(IMyInterface))

where _ImportedType.GetInterfaces()[0]_ is IMyInterface. However IsEquivalentTo return false, even if I'm actually comparing **the same**, identical interface! The only difference is that _ImportedType.GetInterfaces()[0]_ is the one imported from the external dll.

Comment: Wow... so ImportedType.Name == NameOfTypeToImport and ImportedType.FullName == "System.MonoType". Unfortunately, I cannot help you more, this issue is to strange without being able to reproduce it ;(